# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setimmediate

I want to get my id with setImmediate and copy it with CopyToClipboard. I guess I'm pulling the value as blank on the page because the setImmediate function has been removed. What can I use instead of this function and get my id value?

This is the error I get in the console. I tried to print the id in options.jsx and it comes up blank as you can see.

[image]

This is my page view. When I click the blue button, an id needs to be copied and I want to paste that id into the input and start a search. However, I cannot perform the operation because the id is empty.

[image]

SocketContext.js file (take the id)

```js
import React, { createContext, useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import Peer from 'simple-peer';

const SocketContext = createContext();
const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [stream, setStream] = useState(null);
    const [me, setMe] = useState('');
    const [call, setCall] = useState(null);
    const [callAccepted, setCallAccepted] = useState(false);
    const [callEnded, setCallEnded] = useState(false);
    const [name, setName] = useState('');

    const myVideo = useRef();
    const userVideo = useRef();
    const connectionRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
            .then((currentStream) => {
                setStream(currentStream);
                if (myVideo.current) {
                    myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
                };
            });
            
            
            // HERE 
        socket.on('me', (id) => setImmediate(id));
        
        
        socket.on('calluser', ({ from, name: callerName, signal }) => {
            setCall({ isReceivedCall: true, from, name: callerName, signal })
        });
    }, []);

    const answerCall = () => {
        setCallAccepted(true);

        const peer = new Peer({ initiator: false, trickle: false, stream });

        peer.on('signal', (data) => {
            socket.emit('answercall', { signal: data, to: call.from });
        });

        peer.on('stream', (currentStream) => {
            userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
        });
        peer.signal(call.signal);
        connectionRef.current = peer;
    }

    const callUser = (id) => {
        const peer = new Peer({ initiator: true, trickle: false, stream });
        peer.on('signal', (data) => {
            socket.emit('calluser', { userToCall: id, signalData: data, from: me, name });
        });
        peer.on('stream', (currentStream) => {
            userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
        });
        socket.on('callaccepted', (signal) => {
            setCallAccepted(true);
            peer.signal(signal);
        });
        connectionRef.current = peer;
    }

    const leaveCall = () => {
        setCallEnded(true);
        connectionRef.current.destroy();
        window.location.reload();
    }

    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider value={{
            call, callAccepted, myVideo, userVideo, stream, name, setName, callEnded, me, callUser, leaveCall,
            answerCall
        }}>
            {children}
        </SocketContext.Provider>
    );
}

export { ContextProvider, SocketContext };
```

Options.jsx file (copy to id)

```js
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Button, TextField, Grid, Typography, Container, Paper } from "@mui/material";
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { CopyToClipboard } from 'react-copy-to-clipboard';
import { Assignment, Phone, PhoneDisabled } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { SocketContext } from "../SocketContext";

const theme = createTheme();

const rootStyles = {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
};
const gridContainerStyles = {
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
};
const containerStyles = {
    width: '800px',
    margin: '10px 0',
    padding: 0,
    [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
        width: '80%',
    },
};
const marginStyles = {
    marginTop: 2,
};
const paddingStyles = {
    padding: 2,
};
const paperStyles = {
    padding: '1px 2px',
    border: '2px solid black',
};

const Options = ({ children }) => {
    const { me, callAccepted, name, setName, callEnded, leaveCall, callUser } = useContext(SocketContext);
    const [idToCall, setIdToCall] = useState('');

    return (
        <Container sx={containerStyles}>
            <Paper elevation={10} sx={paperStyles}>
                <form sx={rootStyles} noValidate autoComplete="off00">
                    <Grid container sx={gridContainerStyles}>
                        <Grid item xs={12} md={6} sx={paddingStyles}>
                            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6">Account Info</Typography>
                            <TextField label="Name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                                fullWidth />
                                
                                
                            {/* COPY TO ID PART*/}
                            {console.log(me)}
                            <CopyToClipboard text={me} sx={marginStyles} >
                                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" fullWidth
                                    startIcon={<Assignment fontSize="large" />}>
                                    Copy Your ID
                                </Button>
                            </CopyToClipboard>
                            
                            
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12} md={6} sx={paddingStyles}>
                            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6">Make a Call</Typography>
                            <TextField label="ID to Call" value={idToCall}
                                onChange={(e) => setIdToCall(e.target.value)}
                                fullWidth />
                            {callAccepted && !callEnded ? (
                                <Button variant="contained" color="danger" fullWidth
                                    startIcon={<PhoneDisabled fontSize="large" />} onClick={leaveCall}
                                    sx={marginStyles}>Hang Up</Button>
                            ) : (
                                <Button variant="contained" color="success" fullWidth
                                    startIcon={<Phone fontSize="large" />} onClick={() => callUser(idToCall)}
                                    sx={marginStyles}>Call</Button>
                            )}
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </form>
                {children}
            </Paper>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Options
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate#browser_compatibility

Comment: I've looked here and I know it's no longer used, I used postMessage instead but I still keep getting the value blank

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with `setImmediate(id)`? The first parameter of `setImmediate` should be a function, but `id` is some kind of value, isn't it?

Comment: Here is me in index.js io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
    socket.emit('me', socket.id);
}); I am trying to send id value from socketcontext to options

Comment: Well, yes, but what's the purpose of `setImmediate` in that case, that doesn't "send" or "set" anything. It just calls the function that was passed as first parameter. But in your case that `id` is not a function but a value. So even if `setImmediate` was still available, that wouldn't work ...

Comment: That's how he did it in the tutorial I watched, and it works in that. So how can I send this id to my options file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're calling `setImmediate` but that is not defined (which makes sense because setImmediate is a function of window, not a standalone function).

Using some context clues, ie based on how your copy works, do you mean to use `setMe` there? I'm guessing your code editor auto-corrected `setMe` to `setImmediate`. The comment above assumes you're actually trying to use `setImmediate` but it doesn't make sense that you'd be using that here, and `setMe` is unused AND your copy function is using `me`, so I'm almost certain it's a typo.

e.g:
instead of:
`socket.on('me', (id) => setImmediate(id));`

`socket.on('me', (id) => setMe(id));`

Comment: That's how he did it in the tutorial I watched, and it works in that... This works too, thank you so much, you saved me!

Comment: No problem! Something I've learned over the years with tutorials, is that a lot of them are  made in a way where the creator first writes the code off recording, then starts recording and just types out the code again while reading it from a second monitor, almost like a news anchor reading from a teleprompter, so they'll make mistakes and not catch them because they're not thinking about what the code is actually doing anymore. That may have been what happened here.

Comment: Probably that's the problem, you're right.