# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isReceivedCall')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I am trying to make a video chat app. I want the answer button to be activated when a call comes in. But I am getting this error:

[image]

My Notification.jsx file looks like this:

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { SocketContext } from '../SocketContext';

const Notification = () => {
    const { answerCall, call, callAccepted, isReceivedCall } = useContext(SocketContext);

    return (
        <>
            {call.isReceivedCall && !callAccepted && (
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
                    <h1>{call.name} is calling:</h1>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={answerCall}>
                        Answer
                    </Button>
                </div>
            )}
            Notification
        </>
    )
}

export default Notification
```

This is how I defined isReceivedCall in SocketContext:

```js
socket.on('calluser', ({ from, name: callerName, signal }) => {
            setCall({ isReceivedCall: true, from, name: callerName, signal })
        });
    }, []);
```

Comment: If call can be null, try using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):  `call?.isReceivedCall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `console.log` in the component, you will probably find that it renders once, then gets context and renders again. The issue is that the first render, `SocketContext` is null.

So you need to just handle that appropriately, perhaps like:

```
if(!call) return <></<>

return (
        <>
            {call.isReceivedCall && !callAccepted && (
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
                    <h1>{call.name} is calling:</h1>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={answerCall}>
                        Answer
                    </Button>
                </div>
            )}
            Notification
        </>
    )
```

But also a bit confused, looks like you pull `call` from context, as well as `isCallReceived` but `isCallReceived` is a property of `call`. It seems like you dont want to pull `isCallReceived` off of context in the first place.

In other words, you destructure `isCallReceived` here: `const { answerCall, call, callAccepted, isReceivedCall } = useContext(SocketContext);`

but that property exists on call. Unless you just have two different `isReceivedCall` values, which in that case, ignore this confusion.

Comment: This works for me, thank you so much! And I have another problem in the same project, If you don't mind, do you have a chance to have a look at it? Here the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75841368/uncaught-in-promise-referenceerror-setimmediate-is-not-defined?noredirect=1#comment133778525_75841368

Comment: Thanks for accepting! Just took a look at your other question and gave an answer there as well.